# Why are Java EE API's themselves implemented by makers of application servers?

Tags: java-ee-7, application-server, java

Am I seeing a fundamental difference between how Java **Standard** API and Java **EE** API's are implemented?

Java Standard API is up here, implemented by Oracle, for anyone to use in Java programming:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api

But why is it that makers (i.e. IBM, RedHat, Oracle) of application servers (i.e. JBoss, WebLogic, WebSphere, GlassFish, WildFly) come up with different implementations of the same Java EE API?

**Example-1:** RESTEasy is an implementation of JAX-RS available with JBoss

**Example-2:** HornetQ is an implementation of JMS available with WildFly

I guess I should ask, **"What does it even mean to have this EE API page on the Oracle website since every vendor has its own implementation? Is the link below just for a show?"**
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption is not entirely correct.

There are in fact several implementations of Java SE besides the most widely used oracle distribution. The biggest ones are OpenJDK and IBM's JDK.

So, the Java SE API's have a spec just like Java EE does, each with different implementations. The oracle api links you posted are merely requirements for the interfaces, but there still needs to be an implementation for these APIs whether it's Java SE or Java EE.

Comment: Bravo!I However, I still wonder why all those nicknames (i.e. HornetQ, RESTEasy) are necessary in order to refer to specific implementations made by specific vendors. Shouldn't the vendor names or app server names suffice to let people know what particular implementations are being used?

Comment: These are implementations of sub-categories of the Java EE spec (i.e. JMS or JAX-RS), and sometimes these technologies can be used standalone (not as part of an app server) so the naming is just to differentiate themselves, because they are essentially individual products.

Comment: What a concept! As you said "sometimes", I would appreciate if you could list a few more of those sub-categories of JEE specifications that are, in practice, capable of being used standalone products.

Comment: Other examples (although not Java-EE) off the top of my head are JDBC and JPA.  In JDBC there are lots of different datbases each with their own JDBC driver implementation.  For JPA (has a JavaEE spec but also usable in JavaSE standalone).  Implementations of JPA are Hibernate, EclipseLink, and OpenJPA.